# jQuery - add content in on mouseover using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

As the title suggests, I have jQuery tooltip and on mouse over I would like to use an AJAX request to put some data in. Without using a plugin (as seen on all other examples) is this at all possible? This is what I currently have not working.

```
<script>
j$(document).ready(function(e) {
j$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip({
        content: '... waiting on ajax ...',
        open: function(evt, ui) {
            var elem = $(this);
            $.ajax('../include/vessel-count.php').always(function() {
                elem.tooltip('option', 'content', 'Ajax call complete');
             });
        }
    });
});
</script>

<?php
    //This is in a while loop displaying a lot of these.
    echo '<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="words: '.$vessel_Info.'">More - DEV</a>';
?>
```

Ideally I'd like to pass some content into vessel-count.php to perform a few actions and spit the result into the tooltip. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: elem variable doesn't exist in the scope of callback function. Consider passing some kind of identifier to ajax request, return it to callback functiton, and then use it to obtain the element again.

Comment: elem does exist in the scope of the callback.